# Long to wide format: keep row orders and use only part of row values for newly created column names

Tags: r, data.table, pattern-matching, reshape, tidyr

**My data:**

```
> print(DT)
          scenario     hyear          P
 1:  flux_0_P1.0_1 2013-2014 0.14044214
 2:  flux_0_P1.0_1 2014-2015 0.09141671
 3:  flux_0_P1.0_2 2013-2014 0.69610343
 4:  flux_0_P1.0_2 2014-2015 0.52359157
 5:  flux_0_P1.0_3 2013-2014 0.89724457
 6:  flux_0_P1.0_3 2014-2015 0.78003786
 7: flux_0_P1.0_10 2013-2014 0.73752843
 8: flux_0_P1.0_10 2014-2015 0.62216371
 9: flux_0_P1.0_11 2013-2014 0.14259943
10: flux_0_P1.0_11 2014-2015 0.15309200
11: flux_0_P1.0_12 2013-2014 0.81472886
12: flux_0_P1.0_12 2014-2015 0.66015071
```

**I'd like to change from long to wide format which:**

- keeps the row orders in `scenario` column in the newly created wide data frame (data.table) columns e.g. `1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12` NOT `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3`
- uses only part (match and replace pattern) of the row values in `scenario` column as column names in the wide data frame (data.table) e.g. from `flux_0_P1.0_1` to `P_0_P1.0_1` (`P` is the name of the value column in the original data frame)

  ```
    hyear     P_0_P1.0_1 P_0_P1.0_2 P_0_P1.0_3 P_0_P1.0_10 P_0_P1.0_11 P_0_P1.0_12
  1 2013-2014     0.140       0.696      0.897       0.738       0.143       0.815
  2 2014-2015     0.0914      0.524      0.780       0.622       0.153       0.660
  ```

**My attempt so far**: Both `spread` and `dcast` changed the order of the `key` column

```
### tidyverse
DT_wide_tidyr <- tidyr::spread(DT, scenario, P)
DT_wide_tidyr

> DT_wide_tidyr
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  hyear     flux_0_P1.0_1 flux_0_P1.0_10 flux_0_P1.0_11 flux_0_P1.0_12 flux_0_P1.0_2 flux_0_P1.0_3
  <chr>             <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2013-2014        0.140           0.738          0.143          0.815         0.696         0.897
2 2014-2015        0.0914          0.622          0.153          0.660         0.524         0.780

### data.table
DT_wide_dcast <- data.table::dcast(DT, hyear ~ scenario, value.var = "P")
DT_wide_dcast

> DT_wide_dcast
       hyear flux_0_P1.0_1 flux_0_P1.0_10 flux_0_P1.0_11 flux_0_P1.0_12 flux_0_P1.0_2 flux_0_P1.0_3
1: 2013-2014    0.14044214      0.7375284      0.1425994      0.8147289     0.6961034     0.8972446
2: 2014-2015    0.09141671      0.6221637      0.1530920      0.6601507     0.5235916     0.7800379
```

**Data used**

```
> dput(as.data.frame(DT))
structure(list(scenario = c("flux_0_P1.0_1", "flux_0_P1.0_1", 
"flux_0_P1.0_2", "flux_0_P1.0_2", "flux_0_P1.0_3", "flux_0_P1.0_3", 
"flux_0_P1.0_10", "flux_0_P1.0_10", "flux_0_P1.0_11", "flux_0_P1.0_11", 
"flux_0_P1.0_12", "flux_0_P1.0_12"), hyear = c("2013-2014", "2014-2015", 
"2013-2014", "2014-2015", "2013-2014", "2014-2015", "2013-2014", 
"2014-2015", "2013-2014", "2014-2015", "2013-2014", "2014-2015"
), P = structure(c(0.140442142857143, 0.0914167142857143, 0.696103428571428, 
0.523591571428571, 0.897244571428571, 0.780037857142857, 0.737528428571428, 
0.622163714285714, 0.142599428571429, 0.153092, 0.814728857142857, 
0.660150714285714))), .Names = c("scenario", 
"hyear", "P"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thank you and Happy New Year!

**Edit**

Based on the solution provided by @G. Grothendieck, this is what I ended up using:

```
# Set row order in scenario column
DT[, scenario := factor(scenario, levels = unique(scenario))]

# tidyr
DT_wide_tidyr <- tidyr::spread(DT, scenario, P) %>% 
  dplyr::rename_at(vars(contains("flux")), funs(sub("flux", names(DT)[3], .)))
DT_wide_tidyr

# data.table
DT_wide_dcast <- data.table::dcast(DT, hyear ~ scenario, value.var = names(DT)[3])
names(DT_wide_dcast) <- gsub("flux", names(DT)[3], names(DT_wide_dcast))
DT_wide_dcast
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: Seems it still still gives an error when I try to `source` it. Maybe `dput` cannot handle the `ts` column?  Perhaps you could show the output of `print(DT)` together with code that would read that in and construct `DT` from it.

Comment: Sorry about that! I updated my post. Can you try that again? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your solutions would work if the `scenario` column were changed to a factor with the given levels in the desired order.

If `DF` is the input shown at the end of the question then use your code with `DF2` shown here:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, scenario = factor(scenario, levels = unique(scenario)))
```

If `wide` is the result of your code then this will change `flux` to `P` in the column names:

```
names(wide) <- sub("flux", "P", names(wide))
```

Comment: Can you make it more generic e.g. column `P` can also be `T`, `V`, `W`, .etc depending on the long-format data frame? Thanks!

Comment: There is no T, V or W in the data in the question. Please fix the question if it is incomplete or if this would materially change the question (which I suspect) then start a new one or else you may get downvoted for a material change after it has been answered.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! What I meant was I'd like a more generic solution instead of hard-coded letter `P`. Something like this: `names(wide) <- sub("flux", names(DF2)[3], names(wide))`

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
DT$scenario <- gsub('flux_', 'P_', DT$scenario)
DT$scenario <- gsub('(?<=0_)(\\d)$', '0\\1', DT$scenario, perl = TRUE)
DT <- tidyr::spread(DT, scenario, P)
```

#### Result

```
      hyear P_0_P1.0_01 P_0_P1.0_02 P_0_P1.0_03 P_0_P1.0_10 P_0_P1.0_11
1 2013-2014  0.14044214   0.6961034   0.8972446   0.7375284   0.1425994
2 2014-2015  0.09141671   0.5235916   0.7800379   0.6221637   0.1530920
  P_0_P1.0_12
1   0.8147289
2   0.6601507
```

#### Explanation

Your problem was because alphabetizing "1", "2", "10" results in "1", "10", "2". This problem goes away if you add the leading zeros.

#### Update

You can generalize this with the following function:

```
custom_spread <- function(data, key, value, strip_name = NULL) {
    if ( !is.null(strip_name) ) {
        data[, key] <- gsub(strip_name, key, data[, key])
    }
    data[, key] <- gsub('(?<=0_)(\\d)$', '0\\1', data[, key], perl = TRUE)
    data <- tidyr::spread(data, key, value)
    colnames(data) <- gsub('(?<=0_)0(\\d)$', '\\1', colnames(data), perl = TRUE)
    return(data)
}
```

For example, using it with your problem:

```
custom_spread(DT, 'scenario', 'P', strip_name = 'flux')
```

Still gives the same result:

```
      hyear scenario_0_P1.0_1 scenario_0_P1.0_2 scenario_0_P1.0_3
1 2013-2014        0.14044214         0.6961034         0.8972446
2 2014-2015        0.09141671         0.5235916         0.7800379
  scenario_0_P1.0_10 scenario_0_P1.0_11 scenario_0_P1.0_12
1          0.7375284          0.1425994          0.8147289
2          0.6221637          0.1530920          0.6601507
```

But you could be using this for any other value column name like "T", "U", etc. This also removes the leading zeros added in to get the column sorting right. If you want to keep the leading zeros, just comment out the line before the `return()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's a interesting hack! Can you make it more generic e.g. column `P` can also be `T`, `V`, `W`, .etc? Also is there another way to sort the column without adding the leading `0` to them?

Comment: @thecatalyst No prob! PS: If you want to lose the leading zeros in the column names after that, you can just run: `colnames(DT) <- gsub('(?<=0_)0(\\d)$', '\\1', colnames(DT), perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry I was typing too fast. Please see my edited comment!